# Is there a cache or a limit that would mess up composer requires from a gitolite server?

Tags: git, composer-php, gitolite, sshd

I have a gitolite server on digital ocean.  It's hosting a growing number of composer packages.  I seem to get "port 22: Connection refused" when I run composer require some/package IF that package has a lot of dependancies.  I've gone thru the sshd_conf - and that stuff is pretty well documented anyway - but does anyone know if gitolite has some limits I can adjust?  I know gitolite takes over the ssh connection, but I can't find anything in the rc to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Soes anyone know if gitolite has some limits I can adjust?

That is what the [Gitolite Performance](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/perf/) describes:

> TOP TIP: If you have more than 2000 or so repos, then you should be using v3.2 or later;

If the issue persists, that might be a problem on the server (Digital Ocean) side, and their support should look into it.
[This thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-tried-to-ssh-root-ipaddress-i-received-error-port-22-connection-refused) mentions several possibilities, including:

> You [could] have a IPS like fail2ban, which has blocked you for some reason. Go to the console and restart fail2ban, which normally clears any blocking:
>   service fail2ban restart

The [OP Tarek Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4740921/tarek-adam) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469067/is-there-a-cache-or-a-limit-that-would-mess-up-composer-requires-from-a-gitolite/49469140#comment85947224_49469140):

> Turned out to be ufw. (fail2ban was installed but idle.)
>   Same difference though (firewall related)

Comment: Buddy, this is great info.  Thank you so much.  I'm pretty well zonk'd for the day, but I'll dig into this tonight.  Much appreciated.  I'll double back and shoot you some points and plus' if it all pans out.  Again, much appreciated.  Have a great weekend!

Comment: Thanks bro.  It's fail2ban.  Never thought to look there because it's all successful authentication.

Comment: Turned out to be ufw.  (fail2ban was installed but idle.)  Same difference though (firewall related) - so thanks again!

Comment: @TarekAdam Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.